# JQuery Device auto Rotation fixation

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-7

I am working on a website responsive where I need to stop landscape view & only show the portrait View. Can any body please suggest me how can I do that?

I have used this in my code to detect the device orientation but when you tilt your device from portrait to landscape it does not work.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight){
                alert("Please use portrait!");
            } 
});
```

Then I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
      // Announce the new orientation number
      alert(window.orientation);
    }, false);
});
```

It seems OK but now I am not able to hide the landscape view. Please help.

Thanks!